# find the male employees who works on more than one projects

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following schema:

> employee(fname,lname,e_no,age,address,sex,slary,dept_number)
>
> dpartment(dept_name,dept_number,dept_location)
>
> project(pname,pnumber,plocation,dept_number)
>
> works_on(e_no,pnumber,hours)

need to find the name of the male employees who works on more than one project.I created the following sql statement .But it is not working .What is my error and how i can fix it ?

```
SELECT `fname`,`lname` 
FROM `employee`,`works_on`
ON`employee.`e_no`=`works_on`.`e_no` 
WHERE `employee`.`sex`='male' 
GROUP BY `employee`.`e_no` 
HAVING COUNT(works_on.e_no)>1;
```

Comment: Syntax error (comma instead of JOIN keyword), invalid group by etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test by `pnumber` not by `e_no` in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT fname, lname
FROM employee
JOIN works_on
ON employee.e_no = works_on.e_no
WHERE employee.sex = 'male' 
GROUP BY fname, lname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT works_on.pnumber) > 1;
```

**Note:** You should use explicit join syntax instead of old-style implicit syntax.

Comment: whiel running your sql i am getting this error :  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON `employee`.`e_no`=`works_on`.`e_no` WHERE `employee`.`sex`='male' GROUP BY `f' at line 1

Comment: yes..tnanks..it works now...can you explan the having clause a bit...why it should be by "pnumber",why not "e_no" ?

Comment: @AL-zami It is more safe. Say you have records like `(e_no, pnumber) = (1, 10), (1, 10)`. `COUNT(DISTINCT works_on.pnumber)` returns 1, whereas `COUNT(works_on.e_no)` returns 2.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
select t.fname, t.lname from employee t
where t.sex = 'male' and t.e_no in (select e_no from works_on)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate before the join, this should be more efficient (the conditon on `sex` is not very selective):

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee
WHERE sex = 'male' 
AND e_no IN
 (
   SELECT e_no
   FROM works_on
   GROUP BY e_no
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 )
```

If the combination of `(e_no,pnumber)` is not unique:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pnumber) > 1
```